# Difficult SQL query syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hello guys here are my MySQL query which one getting data...

```
$videofetch = $conn->prepare("select * from user_followers as uf join videos as v on uf.followed_id = v.publisher_id where uf.follower_id = ? order by video_id desc limit 5");
$videofetch->execute(array(@$_SESSION ["userid"]));
$vid = $videofetch->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This code is working perfect, But when i am trying to get more data with AJAX i can't write the correct sql query syntax.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])) {
  include('connectdb.php');
  $lastID = $_POST['id'];
  $videofetch = $conn->prepare("select * from  user_followers as uf join videos  as v  on uf.followed_id = v.publisher_id where uf.follower_id = ? order by video_id  desc limit 5");
  $videofetch->execute(array($_SESSION["userid"]));
  $vid = $videofetch->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  ...
```

I want to add `WHERE video_id < ".$lastID."` .. I tryed couple of combinations but everytime displaying syntax error.

Notes:

1- I am getting data from AJAX to `$lastID`;

2- `$_SESSION ["userid"]` is active, dont worry about this

3-SQL error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'as v on uf.followed_id = v.publisher_id where
>   uf.follower_id = '1' order by vid' at line 1 in
>   C:\wamp64\www\hola.com\functions\getdatafoll.php on line 9

Comment: `videos as v` => `videos v` - you use `AS` for aliasing columns, not tables.

Comment: Take the AS out of your table alias for videos

Comment: first query is working godd just i want to add `WHERE video_id < ".$lastID."` to second query

Comment: I will try thank you for reply

Comment: I tryed couple of combinations without `as` but still same syntax error :)

Comment: `$videofetch = $conn->prepare("select * from  user_followers as uf join videos v  WHERE video_id < ".$lastID." on uf.followed_id = v.publisher_id where uf.follower_id = ? order by video_id  desc limit 5");`

Comment: `$videofetch = $conn->prepare("select * from  user_followers as uf join videos v   on uf.followed_id = v.publisher_id where uf.follower_id = ? order by video_id  desc and video_id < ".$lastID." limit 5");`

Comment: I can use , and i am using: This code is working perfectly... `select * from user_followers as uf join videos as v on uf.followed_id = v.publisher_id where uf.follower_id = ? order by video_id desc limit 5` The problem is I want to add this somewhere : `WHERE video_id < ".$lastID."`

Comment: @Qirel - `AS` works fine for table aliasing, too.

Comment: Please mark the useful answer as accepted :)

Comment: Sticking things like `@$_SESSION` in development code is really unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upercase your mysql keywords. its much better to read.

And you already have a WHERE, so you just need to combine it with an AND.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  user_followers AS uf
    JOIN  videos AS v  ON uf.followed_id = v.publisher_id
    WHERE  uf.follower_id = ?
      AND  video_id < ".$lastID."
    ORDER BY  video_id DESC
    LIMIT  5
```

But change the ' ".$lastID." with a prepared statment.

Comment: Thats it bro this is the correct answer thank you so much,`$videofetch = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_followers AS uf JOIN videos AS v on uf.followed_id = v.publisher_id WHERE uf.follower_id = ? AND video_id < ".$lastID." ORDER BY video_id DESC LIMIT 5");
$videofetch->execute(array($_SESSION["userid"]));`